# InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.vehicle.datatransferobject.VehicleDTO`

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

In the REST endpoint I'm building in Spring Boot, I'm trying to pass my `vehicleDTO` to my controller. But before it reaches my controller, there is an error.

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of
>   `com.vehicle.datatransferobject.VehicleDTO` (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate-
>   or property-based Creator)

**vehicleDTO**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.myvehicle.EngineType;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class VehicleDTO {

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "vehiclenumber can not be null!")
    private String vehiclenumber;

    @Min(2)
    @NotNull(message = "Seat count can not be less than 2!")
    private Integer vehicleseatcount;

    @NotNull(message = "Engine Type can not be null!")
    private EngineType enginetype;

    @Max(5)
    private Integer vehiclerating;



    private VehicleDTO(Long id, String vehiclenumber, Integer vehicleseatcount, EngineType enginetype,Integer vehiclerating){
        this.vehiclenumber=vehiclenumber;
        this.vehicleseatcount=vehicleseatcount;
        this.enginetype=enginetype;
        this.vehiclerating=vehiclerating;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public static VehicleDTOBuilder newBuilder()
    {
        return new VehicleDTOBuilder();
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getvehiclenumber() {
        return vehiclenumber;
    }


    public Integer getvehicleseatcount() {
        return vehicleseatcount;
    }


    public EngineType getEnginetype() {
        return enginetype;
    }



    public Integer getvehiclerating() {
        return vehiclerating;
    }




    public static class VehicleDTOBuilder{

        private Long id;
        private String vehiclenumber;
        private Integer vehicleseatcount;
        private EngineType enginetype;
        private Integer vehiclerating;

        public VehicleDTOBuilder setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }
        public VehicleDTOBuilder setvehiclenumber(String vehiclenumber) {
            this.vehiclenumber = vehiclenumber;
            return this;
        }
        public VehicleDTOBuilder setvehicleseatcount(Integer vehicleseatcount) {
            this.vehicleseatcount = vehicleseatcount;
            return this;
        }
        public VehicleDTOBuilder setEnginetype(EngineType enginetype) {
            this.enginetype = enginetype;
            return this;
        }
        public VehicleDTOBuilder setvehiclerating(Integer vehiclerating) {
            this.vehiclerating = vehiclerating;
            return this;
        }


        public VehicleDTO createVehicleDTO()
        {
            return new VehicleDTO(id, vehiclenumber, vehicleseatcount, enginetype,vehiclerating);
        }

    }

}
```

My DTO has an Enum type called EngineType

```
public enum EngineType {
    ELECTRIC, DIESEL
}
```

My controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public VehicleDTO addvehicle(@Valid @RequestBody VehicleDTO vehicleDTO) 
    {
        VehicleDO vehicleDO = Mapper.VehicleDO(vehicleDTO);
        return Mapper.makeVehicleDTO(Service.addvehicle(vehicleDO));
    }
```

Comment: have you tried adding a default constructor to VehicleDTO?

Answer (score 15):

This exception :

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of
>   com.vehicle.datatransferobject.VehicleDTO (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate-
>   or property-based Creator)

means that Jackson didn't find a way to instantiate `VehicleDTO` that is the default constructor (no arg constructor) or a `JsonCreator`.
As you use a builder pattern you will configure the `VehicleDTO` class to make Jackson to instantiate `VehicleDTO`  with the `VehicleDTOBuilder` such as :

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = VehicleDTO.VehicleDTOBuilder.class)
public class VehicleDTO {
      ...         
}
```

And annotate your builder with [JsonPOJOBuilder](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonPOJOBuilder.html) as :

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "createVehicleDTO", withPrefix = "set")
public static class VehicleDTOBuilder{ 
   ...
}
```

According to the javadoc, `JsonPOJOBuilder` is :

> used to configure details of a Builder class: instances of which are
>   used as Builders for deserialized POJO values, instead of POJOs being
>   instantiated using constructors or factory methods. Note that this
>   annotation is NOT used to define what is the Builder class for a POJO:
>   rather, this is determined by JsonDeserialize.builder() property of
>   JsonDeserialize.

Comment: thanks this worked. So if i had a public constructor then i wouldn't have faced this issue is it?

Comment: Exactly. You can test it ! Few years early you would have added a no arg constructor or a factory method but Jackson improves the way to instantiate the objects.

Comment: So builder method is the right way to create my DTO to send as response? is it the standard? Or should i change my code?

Comment: I suppose that you use a builder to make your DTO immutable and with a consistent state. If it is the case you want to keep this way. Jackson just adapted its way to work to cover different ways to instantiate an object.

Comment: can you look at one more issue here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383872/spring-boot-dto-is-null-at-controller?noredirect=1#comment89740063_51383872

Answer (score 11):

I faced this error when I used Lombok's `@Builder` and `@Data` annotations together on a POJO class that is used for connecting to an API (either for consuming or for providing response)

I removed the `@Builder` annotation and then it is working fine

Answer (score 7):

In my case:

```
InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.vehicle.datatransferobject.VehicleDTO (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

for the above exception, I just write **Default Constructor** which instantiates class and solved the problem.

**Default Constructor:**

```
public VehicleDTO() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Lombok - the best thing is to add these annotations to your DTO:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder (optional)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270371/davidxxx)`s answer. I used Lombok. And in my case it looked like this:

```
@Data
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "SomeClassBuilder")
public class SomeClass {
    // ...

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class SomeClassBuilder {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution here that worked with lombok. (adding the empty static builder class in the class)