# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jaxb

I am currently trying to map a request from JSON request directly to an XML definition. The Idea is that I have a Spring Boot application consuming SOAP services and exposing them as RESTful services;

Below is the SOAP binding class definition;

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "log",
    "pass",
    "idNumber",
    "serialNumber"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetDataByIdCard")
public class GetDataByIdCard {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "log", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> log;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "pass", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> pass;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "id_number", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> idNumber;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "serial_number", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> serialNumber;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the log property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public JAXBElement<String> getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the log property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public void setLog(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.log = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the pass property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public JAXBElement<String> getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the pass property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public void setPass(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.pass = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the idNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public JAXBElement<String> getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the idNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public void setIdNumber(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.idNumber = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the serialNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public JAXBElement<String> getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the serialNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     *     
     */
    public void setSerialNumber(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.serialNumber = value;
    }

}
```

Below is my Controller;

```
@Autowired
private IPRSClient client;

@PostMapping("/getbyId")
public GetDataByIdCardResponse invokeGetbyIdCard(@RequestBody GetDataByIdCard IdCardRequest) {

    return client.getById(IdCardRequest);
}
```

When I perform a Post Request I'm getting the below error log;

```
2019-11-13 08:51:12.829 ERROR 21148 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('RES')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.iprs.soap.api.bindingclasses.GetDataByIdCard["log"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('RES')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.iprs.soap.api.bindingclasses.GetDataByIdCard["log"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

The Ideal result I'm looking for is to perform a Post request to my RESTful service and have it mapped to the XML service; the `JAXBElement` is proving to be a challenge when I try this.

**EDIT**
I've tried mapping with my own custom class as shown below;

```
public class IdCardCredentials {

    public IdCardCredentials() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @JsonProperty("log")
    private String log;
    @JsonProperty("pass")
    private String pass;
    @JsonProperty("id_Number")
    private String idNumber;
    @JsonProperty("serialNumber")
    private String serialNumber;

    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }
    public void setLog(String log) {
        this.log = log;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }
    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

}
```

I've also updated the controller to the below definition;

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class IprsWsClientApplication {

    @Autowired
    private IPRSClient client;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @PostMapping("/getbyId")
    public GetDataByIdCardResponse invokeGetbyIdCard(@RequestBody IdCardCredentials IdCardRequest) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(IdCardRequest.getIdNumber() + "------ID NUMBER-----");

        GetDataByIdCard IdcardReq = modelMapper.map(IdCardRequest, GetDataByIdCard.class);

        System.out.println(IdcardReq.getIdNumber() + "------REAL ID NUMBER-----");

        return client.getById(IdcardReq);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IprsWsClientApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

However the Mapper doesn't assign the values approapriately; that is all values are null. I'm looking for a way I can map the values to this SOAP class Definition.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you have `@XmlElementRef` instead of plain `@XmlElement`? With latter, you wouldn't have to use unnecessary `JAXBElement<String>` wrapper  but just `String`. Problem being that `JAXBElement` adds unnecessary strong coupling to XML types where you do not seem to have any need to -- Java String is simpler than wrapper. And that is also problem Jackson has: it does not deal with JAXB/XML specific types although it does understand JAXB annotations.

Comment: The API I'm consuming is legacy code; the code base is not in my control; I generated the Java Binding classes using the `XJC` tool and `jaxb2-maven-plugin `

Comment: you may find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383318/11486142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a very long walk around to this issue; Instead of Using the `ModelMapper` I changed to `ObjectFactory` as shown below;

```
@PostMapping("/getbyId")
public GetDataByIdCardResponse invokeGetbyIdCard(@RequestBody IdCardCredentials IdCardRequest) {

    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();


    GetDataByIdCard IdcardReq = new GetDataByIdCard();

    JAXBElement<String> idNo = factory.createGetDataByIdCardIdNumber(IdCardRequest.getIdNumber());
    JAXBElement<String> log = factory.createGetDataByIdCardLog(IdCardRequest.getLog());
    JAXBElement<String> pass = factory.createGetDataByIdCardPass(IdCardRequest.getPass());


    IdcardReq.setLog(log);
    IdcardReq.setPass(pass);
    IdcardReq.setPass(idNo);

    return client.getById(IdcardReq);
}
```

Even though it's not Ideal it does the work.